# Move items between 2 ndarrays based on offset provided in a 3rd ndarray

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

In order to compute images stored in ndarrays provided by opencv that are (4000,6000,3) shape i want to copy values from a source ndarray to a target ndarray at different coordinates (x,y) in target. Offset to be added to the source coordinates in order to compute target ones are stored in an ndarray.
See below the simple principle implemented with two nested loops:

```
import numpy as np

source = np.array([
[1,2,3,33],
[4,5,6,66],
[7,8,9,99]])

target = np.array([
[0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0]])

move_instruction = np.array([
                [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
                [[-1,0],[0,0],[1,1],[0,0]],
                [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]])

rows, cols = source.shape
for y in range(rows):
    for x in range(cols):
       y_target = y + move_instruction[y][x][0]
       x_target = x + move_instruction[y][x][1]
       target[y_target][x_target] = source[y][x]
```

Problem is that it is very slow.

I'm beginner with numpy and wondering if there's a smart way to perform this operation with ndarray operations in a more efficient way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the indices of the source array, add the shift to those indices, then assign the values from the source at the positions of the shifted indices on the target.

```
import numpy as np

source = np.array([
[1,2,3,33],
[4,5,6,66],
[7,8,9,99]])

target = np.zeros_like(source)

move_instruction = np.array([
                [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
                [[-1,0],[0,0],[1,1],[0,0]],
                [[-100,100],[-100,0],[0,100],[0,0]]])

all_inds = np.where(np.ones_like(source))
moves = move_instruction[all_inds]
new_r = all_inds[0] + moves[...,0]
new_c = all_inds[1] + moves[...,1]
arr_shape = source.shape

# Filter for invalid shifts
filter = (new_r < 0) + (new_r >= arr_shape[0]) + (new_c < 0) + (new_c >= arr_shape[1])
new_r[filter] = all_inds[0][filter] # This just recovers the original non-moved index;
new_c[filter] = all_inds[1][filter] # if you want to do something else you'll have to
                                    # modify these indices some other way.
new_inds = (new_r, new_c)
target[new_inds] = source[all_inds]
```

Comment: Thanks :-) it does the job very well except when indices go out of scope as you mention in your comment. Unfortunately i do have the case in my data. I guess catching the exception IndexError like i was doing in the stupid loop appproach will not do the job as the assignement operation will be cancelled. Is there a way to filter in new_inds array those indices that will not be valid (negative or > size).    Something based on np.where or similar

Comment: @Thib I modified the answer to provide a filter, but you'll have to figure out what you want to do when `move_instruction` is invalid. The modified answer just doesn't shift for the invalid instructions.

Comment: @Thib also, catching `IndexError` (1) won't help with negative indices (as they just go to the last index instead), and (2) If you wanted to do the loop approach you can catch invalid shifts in the loop and do something else in the `except` part instead of just continuing the loop.

Comment: thanks. Actually what i'll do is to set the value to valid border value. If negative to zero and if > shape to shape.